Countdown timer not interacting correctly
Using flutter and dart to create a widget with a 5 second countdown timer.
Expected Behaviour: User clicks start then the countdown timer will start.
Within the material button I have referenced the void function but unsure why this wont work.
   MaterialButtononPressed: _startCountDown, child: Text('START'),),
The Class used for this implementation is stateful implementation not sure why it's not working.
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepOrange),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Workout page.'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 int timeLeft = 5;
//Timer Method
  void _startCountDown(){
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
        setState(() {
          timeLeft--;
        });
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children:[
            Text(
              timeLeft.toString(), style: TextStyle(fontSize:70),
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: _startCountDown,
              child: Text('START'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}


Checked & Tried: check the function reference

Unable to reproduce the issue. The code is working as intended for me

dont you forget to dismis timer after countdown finished. probably, your timer has been running, then you press again the button.

Hi
I think an issue to do with the hot reset within android studio. This is what the issue was.And yes I've not reset the timer unit; so thanks for mentioning.

The issue is that you're not stopping the timer when it reaches 0.
  Timer? timer;

  //Timer Method
  void _startCountDown(){
    timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      setState(() {
        timeLeft--;
        if (timeLeft <= 0) {
          timer.cancel(); // Stop the timer when it reaches 0
        }
      });
    });
  }

